# Using nested hiera calls

Tags: puppet

> I know people are looking at this and saying its complex, do you really need to do this?  The answer is yes.  The data requires an extra level of indirection to model the entire data set efficiently. The options are to hard code it, with many key/value settings (madness), to use the inbuilt functions to deliver this (doesn't appear to be capable of this) or to deliver this with two separate lookups from puppet (doable, but writing code in puppet modules to do data lookups is wrong).

I am working on a project where the ability to use Hiera to generate a lot of settings based on a few key facts is important.

so, imagine a hiera data file:

`value_options:
  opt1: "data1"
  opt2: "data2"`

`value_template: "value_options.%{value_arg}"`

The simple case:

`options_test1: "%{hiera('value_options.opt1')}"`

sets options_test1 to "data1" as expected

`options_test2: "%{value_arg}"`

sets options_test2 to the value_arg fact's value.

`options_test3: "%{hiera(value_template)}"`

sets options_test3 to the value 'value_options.opt1' when value_arg is set to 'opt1'

That's all well and good.

The problem comes at the final (and useful) point where you want to use the generated hiera string to reference the data value like this:

`options_test4: "%{hiera(hiera(value_template))}"`

I cannot seem to get this to work.

The simple situation where this was always controlled by a fact would be to turn this into layer in the data config file.

`:hierarchy:
  - "options\\%{::arg}"`

and implement:

`value_options: "data..."`

setting its value in the files `options\opt1.yaml` and `options\opt2.yaml`

However, that makes it impossible to do this:

`description: "we have %{value_options.opt1} and %{value_options.opt2} as settings"`

**Has anyone ever solved this?**

Comment: Looks like an overly complicated structure to me. It might be more sensible for you to describe your larger problem and ask whether there is a more direct approach.

Comment: I agree to @FelixFrank. As far as I understand, hiera is a key/value data **lookup** tool rather than computation tool. Maybe ask puppetlabs, directly. I assume, you have tried using the intermediate step using `options_test3` like `options_test4: "%{hiera(options_test3)}"` instead of `options_test4: "%{hiera(hiera(value_template))}"`

Comment: It is complex, because the problem being solved is complex.  I am faced with either having many key key values